# Are there differences between cheap and expensive microfiber lens cloths?

Tags: lens, cleaning

You can find microfiber lens-cleaning cloths on the web for [less than $2](http://www.shopmicrofiber.com/?page=Category.Browse&externalCategoryId=32412), or pay $6 for a ["Canon" microfiber cloth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003G3QK4S) (or buy at a retail camera store for $15-20).  Are all such cloths pretty much the same, or is there a reason to pay more?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't speak to the microfiber cloths specifically, but often the Canon/Nikon-branded small accessories like this really are nothing special. For example, I had some Canon lens cleaning fluid and it was pretty much crap. Stuff like this isn't actually made by them anyway - it's 3rd parties that license the brands.

I've not had great experience with microfiber cloths. For now, I'm trying disposable papers (Pec Pads). A lot of people like Kimwipes. (Oh, and I had some Canon lens paper that was pretty much crap too.)

Comment: I second the disposable cleaning papers/tissues. They are relatively cheap, and do a superb job of cleaning a lens (even when used dry.)

Comment: +1 on the name brand camera ones being nothing special. The canon microfiber cleaning cloth that came with my 5D2 is indistinguishable from the cheap no name one I picked up several years prior for $1 just to bump an online order up a few cents to put it into free shipping realm.  The one exception to that, Zeiss. We buy a box of their pre-moistened single use cleaning papers/tissue in the optical section of the local warehouse store about once a year. Love them for cleaning glass & screens (both cam and lappy) Heck, I think I've even used one for eyeglasses (what they're made for). :)

Answer (score 3):

Microfiber clothes are built specially so that it doesn't leave any scratch while cleaning your sensitive lens/s. If I were you, I wouldn't take any risk which involves leaving a stubborn scratch in my lens or even a minor one, almost invisible to human eyes. These things are mostly cheap, and you can use any one of them available, not necessarily it has to be from your camera manufacturer. I use one which I got with my Sony VAIO for cleaning the LCD screen. Its better if you can ask a few friends what they use before buying one.

And just so you know, for cleaning dust, its recommended to use blowers in general.